# Regular expression inclusion trouble

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to process some PHP code to extract keys from a specific array. I am using regular expressions to do so.

A sample source text :

```
$src = 'if ( $loc["key"] == $val) { // some stuff }';
```

The regex code :

```
preg_match_all('/\$loc\[\"(.+)\"]/',$src,$keys);
```

Which gives me the right answer :

```
key
```

But if change `src` to :

```
$src = 'if ( $loc["key"] == $val ) { $loc["otherkey"] == $val; }';
```

It gives :

```
key"] == $val ) { $loc["otherkey
```

Does anyone have any idea why is it like this, and how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the dot ungreedy by appending "U" to your expression:

```
preg_match_all('/\$loc\[\"(.+)\"]/U',$src,$keys);
```

Or replace the dot with the "but not quote" expression:

```
preg_match_all('/\$loc\[\"([^"]+)\"]/',$src,$keys);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know the "greedy" purpose of regex. And the second solution is also quite elegant :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make `+` [non-greedy(lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
/\$loc\["(.+?)"\]/
```

Otherwise, it tries to match *as many characters as possible* `(.+)` until it finds another `"` (the last one).

Or maybe better is to match all characters *except* double quotes:

```
 /\$loc\["([^"]+)"\]/
```

---

Btw, as you use single quotes for the expression, you don't need to escape the double quotes.